# Is there a representation of the entries of the Moore-Penrose inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. If $A$ is invertible, there is a formula for the entries of $A^{-1}$ involving its adjugate matrix (i.e. minors of $A$). Is there a similar thing for the Moore-Penrose inverse $A^\dagger$ for non-invertible $A$?

Comment: The pseudoinverse is discontinuous, so nothing particularly nice like the adjugate formula. There's a cute limit formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Limit_relations

Comment: What do you mean by discontinuous? It's a matrix.

Comment: I mean it’s a discontinuous function of $A$ (unlike the inverse).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see what you mean. But on the set of rank $m$ matrices it is continuous and I actually found a formula here: http://www.vesnik.math.rs/vol/mv961201.pdf